# java.text.Parseexception, unparseble date at position 0? Android

Tags: java, android, date

I am using the below code to parse a date, and to format it how I want; the code is working fine for other dates such as this one:

Thu, 04 Sep 2014 19:32:00 GMT

But it is throwing the above error message on a date such as this:

Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01:00 +0100

Can anyone explain why?

Thanks.

The code:

```
//Only get the 'important' parts.
pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 23);
//Format it how I want.
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
//Here is where it is breaking.                 
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
//Format it once again to how I want.                   
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
//get the current date and format it the same.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
currDate = sdf.format(new Date());
currDate = currDate.replace(" ", "");
rssDate = dateFormatter.format(date).replace(" ", "");
```

This is the log:

```
09-05 11:30:07.153: E/DATE(7665): Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01
09-05 11:30:07.153: E/ERROR(7665): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "
09-05 11:30:07.153: E/ERROR(7665): Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01" (at offset 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, that does not seemed to have fixed it though :S

Comment: @Callum In my enviroment it works. `   String pubDateFormat ="Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01";
  
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
   //Here is where it is breaking.                 
   Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
   System.out.println(date);` printed : Fri Sep 05 06:01:00 CEST 2014

Comment: @Callum You get the same error like without locale?

Comment: Can you try to parse the fix string not the subtring? So we can veryfie that tere is no leading or trailing blank.

Comment: What exactly do you mean sorry?

Comment: add tHis line `pubDateFormat ="Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01"; ` after this line `pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 23);
` in your code.

Comment: Yes, that no longer brings back the errors, so what does this tell us then? That the pubDate I have has invalid characters or something in it?

Comment: Hi, I have asked a new question; which may make things a bit clearer.

Comment: @Callum For me the new Question is not clearer. It it totally unclear. Can you make a runable example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. No, this does not seem to have done anything either?

Comment: Have you changed the 'SimpleDateFormat' to 'DateFormat'